# How can I select from a dropdown list in protractor?

Tags: node.js, drop-down-menu, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I am struggling with attempting to select a product called "some product" from the following drop down menu.  'id="s2id_autogen81"' is the new ID element, I was using that id to grab the item but it was changed to this auto gen value and I'm not sure what to have protractor grab.

**From the drop-down menu before selecting it**

```
 <div class="select2-container ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" id="s2id_autogen81">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice select2-default" tabindex="-1">   
        <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-82">Select a product</span>
        <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close"></abbr>   
        <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
            <b role="presentation"></b>
        </span>
    </a>
    <label for="s2id_autogen82" class="select2-offscreen"></label>
    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-82" id="s2id_autogen82">
</div>
```

**From the drop-down after selecting it**

```
 <div class="select2-drop select2-display-none select2-with-searchbox  select2-drop-active" id="select2-drop" style="left: 86.4375px; width: 258px;  top: 831px; bottom: auto; display: block;">   
<div class="select2-search">       
<label for="s2id_autogen11_search" class="select2-offscreen">Product</label>       
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-11" id="s2id_autogen11_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-15">   
</div>   
<ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-11"><li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable ng-binding ng-hide" role="presentation">
    <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-13" role="option">
    <span class="select2-match">
        </span>
    </div>
    </li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable ng-binding ng-scope" role="presentation">
    <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-14" role="option">
    <span class="select2-match">
        </span>NOT SOME PRODUCT
    </div>
    </li>
<li class="select2-results-dept-0 select2-result select2-result-selectable ng-binding ng-scope select2-highlighted" role="presentation">
    <div class="select2-result-label" id="select2-result-label-15" role="option">
    <span class="select2-match">
        </span>SOME PRODUCT
    </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Where is that `some product` in the HTML?

Comment: @alecxe I updated the post thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use following code.

```
element.all(by.model('ng-model of the drop down list')).each(function (eachElement, index) 
    {
       eachElement.click();// select the <select>
       browser.driver.sleep(500);// wait for the renderings to take effect
       element(by.css('unique selector of the item you need to select')).click();// select the first md-option
       browser.driver.sleep(500);// wait for the renderings to take effect
   });
```